# Adding a Parameter Binding to an SSIS Package with C#

Tags: c#, ssis

Struggling to work out how to add a parameter mapping to an SSIS SQL Task.

```
so far I am able to create my SQL Task, and set a few properties.
TaskHost taskhost = sequence1.Executables.Add("STOCK:SQLTask") as TaskHost;
                    taskhost.Name = myTable.ToString();
                    taskhost.Properties["Connection"].SetValue(taskhost, connMgrOleDb.Name);
                    taskhost.Properties["SqlStatementSource"].SetValue(taskhost, "EXEC sp_GET_S_" + myTable.ToString() +"?, ?");


 // need to add input parameter binding
```

//    Any ideas??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you are using the TaskHost object to set the properties. Using TaskHost is preferable in cases where you want to set the properties dynamically. Properties can also be set by using the underlying control flow task directly and is preferable in some cases.

So here, you can use the [ExecuteSQLTask](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.tasks.executesqltask.executesqltask.aspx) object directly to add Parameter Bindings. Simply call the Add method on the ParameterBindings property of the ExecuteSqlTask.

To use the ExecuteSqlTask object you need to add a assembly reference to the Microsoft.SqlServer.SQLTask.dll.

So cast the InnerObject of the TaskHost to a ExecuteSqlTask and then call Add method on the ExecuteSqlTask's ParameterBindings property. Same pattern goes for adding Result Bindings also.

```
        // cast the TaskHost's InnerObject as ExecuteSqlTask
        // add a reference to the Microsoft.SqlServer.SQLTask.dll to use ExecuteSqlTask
        ExecuteSQLTask sqlTask = TaskHost.InnerObject as ExecuteSQLTask;

        // call the Add method on ParameterBindings property of sqlTask.
        //This will return a IDTSParameterBinding object
        IDTSParameterBinding parameterBinding = sqlTask.ParameterBindings.Add();

        // using the IDTSParameterBinding object that is returned from the Add call, set the various properties
        parameterBinding.ParameterName = "ParamName";
        parameterBinding.ParameterDirection = ParameterDirections.Input;
        // set more properties on parameterBinding as needed ......
```